# iMac locking immediately after remote connection via Anydesk or Chrome Remote

Tags: imac, catalina, sleep-wake, remote-desktop

I upgraded my iMac Late 2013 to Catalina.  When I login through Anydesk or Chrome Remote Desktop I see my desktop for a split second and then im presented with the lock screen again.

While Anydesk is open, I can press 'switch user' in CRD which then shows me my screensaver.  Then if I start moving around the screen saver eventually quits and I can use my desktop in CRD, while anydesk still sees the switch user screen (the available users and the sleep/restart/shut down options)

After a fresh reboot I was on with CRD & Anydesk.  I closed CRD, and I was back to the starting issue where the screen just locks and using CRD at same time I was able to login.  Sometime later I ended up with total lockout - neither Anydesk or CRD will connect even though I know the Mac is online running scripts.

Two remote connections, same iMac:
[image: 2 remote connections, 1 iMac]

I've also now put in Teamviewer and I have the same issue - as soon as I type my password it locks on me.  It sems like something is locking the cursor because with every letter I type the password field loses focus and I have to click again and quickly type the next letter.

These are the relevant options I can think of:

- Energy Saver: Turn display off after 10 min, prevent auto sleep when display off, put disks to sleep when possible, wake for network, auto start on power failure, enable power nap.
- Screen Saver: Start after Never
- Amphetamine: Launch at login, start session when launch or waking sleep, indefinite duration, allow display sleep, (no screen saver, no forced sleep).  Lock screen after 15 min inactivity, allow display sleep when screen locked.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Amphetamine with the chrome desktop app and it did work great.

My settings: Launch and start session (turned on).
2 screen saver off
3. Display sleep off
4. duration: 12 hours or 24 hours (Indefinitely setting didn't work for me)

All other default energy saver settings were off.